# How to proceed for making chat application using jsp's and servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, chat

I developed a chat application using java.But now my challenge is build a chat app in web application.I dont how to proceed.Can we use sockets as done in java.

Please give me a suggestion to get through this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you to use [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) as they're really efficient to exchange in real time (push instead of pull) data between a server and html clients. They're bidirectionnal and roughly equivalent to the sockets you're used to (hence their name). Client-side, they use the same callback based logic than ajax clients but that doesn't mean they're not fast.

Here's a tutorial : http://java.dzone.com/articles/creating-websocket-chat

Googling "java chat websocket" would give you other results.

Comment: Thanks for your response.Do i need to know about j Query Lang. ?

Comment: You don't *need* to know the jQuery API to use websockets. But jQuery  is a very powerful and useful tool for all web applications so I'd suggest to all new web developers to at least read its tutorial, even if they start without it.

Comment: I'm trying execute that code in eclipse with tomcat web server.But am not getting the output.Web socket object is not creating.Could u help me ?

Comment: @sasikrishna Please ask a different question, with details (code will be needed) for that problem.

Comment: "ws://localhost:8080/BasicWebSocket/WebSocketChatServlet"  This is my URI. WebSocketChatServlet extends WebSocketServlet and another class which implements OnTextMessage.  My problem is URI not connecting to WebSocketChatServlet .ws becomes null after calling constructor of WebSocket.Thanks U