# Is it possible to get other user's session attributes in servlets

Tags: jsp, session, servlets, attributes

I my application I want to get other user's session attributes like his name etc.

Is it possible with `request.getsession.getAttribute("Other User's attribute key")`.

Please Help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You mean you would want to have session attributes in servlets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session is per-"user"; that's the point of sessions.

You could implement a session listener that puts other session data into application context when it's added/removed. Sessions not explicitly closed will leave data in the application context, though.

What specifically are you trying to do? Why are you trying to access session data from another session?

If you're *not* trying to access data from a *different* session, then you can get and put whatever data you want into the session using `setAttribute` and `getAttribute`.

Comment: Thanks for ur response.  Actually i am trying to develop a chat app using Servlets & JSP's. I have a class consists a string field.For every user i create an instance and placing that obj in request scope. so that every other user can access others instance to send his MSG.Is it a correct approach for chatting ?

Comment: @sasikrishna You already have got a good answer here regarding chat application: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12006130/468763 also this might help: http://www.web-tech-india.com/software/jsp_chat.php

Answer (score 0):

First you do this

```
javax.servlet.http.HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

then to set session

```
session.setAttribute("username","value");
```

and then to retrieve

```
String str = (String) session.getAttribute("username");
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks for ur respone but am not asking to get attributes in our own session.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you should be storing such values not in the session scope.If data needs to be accessed across multiple sessions , such data needs to be stored in application scope.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I tried an example using application scope , it worked.but i need some more tutorials.Cud u give any URL regarding Application scope tutorials.          Actually i am trying to develop a chat app using Servlets & JSP's. I have a class consists a string field.For every user i create an instance and placing that obj in application scope. so every other user can access others instance to send his MSG.Is it a correct approach for chatting ?